# SpecFlow - test MVC3 Web site with action calls

Tags: automated-testing, bdd, specflow

I'm very new to BDD testing, and would like to ask, is it possible/OK to test ASP MVC3 actions directly (using `WebClient`) using SpecFlow?

i.e.

```
Feature: Login

Scenario: Logging in
    Given I post form to http://someurl/account/logon with parameters username='test' and password='123'
    Then I expect it to be redirected to the http://someurl/home
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly can. Both WebClient, or HttpRequest would work well as the 'glue' for this scenario.

Note that I'd probably rephrase your Given/When/Then Statement as something like:

```
Given the logon page at http://someurl/account/logon 
When I post with parameters username='test' and password='123'
Then I am redirected to http://someurl/home
```